# How to add a default cookie with Dio via CookieManager in dart

Tags: dart, dio

Dio used to allow setting default cookies in baseOptions such as this.

```dart
final BaseOptions dioBaseOptions = BaseOptions(
    baseUrl: 'http://192.168.1.19',
    headers: {
      "Host": "api.example.test",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    cookies: [
      Cookie('XDEBUG_SESSION', 'PHPSTORM'),
    ],
  );
```

With the updated API this appears to be no longer the case and we need to go with interceptors (or there's an alternative)? Trying to adjust the above code to the new Dio API I have the following except I cannot see how to add a cookie to the jar.

```dart
    var dio = Dio();
    dio.interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(onRequest: (RequestOptions options) async {
      var customHeaders = {
        "Host": "api.example.test",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      };
      options.headers.addAll(customHeaders);
      return options;
    }));

    var cookieJar=CookieJar();
    /// I was expecting something like .add(Cookie(...))
    dio.interceptors.add(CookieManager(cookieJar));
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the only way is to manually write the cookie in the headers

```dart
  final BaseOptions dioBaseOptions = BaseOptions(
    baseUrl: 'http://192.168.1.19',
    headers: {
      'Host': "api.radio.test",
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Cookie': 'XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM',
    },
  );
```